# Handlebars Mustache, Make Indentation Without New Line?

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js, mustache

I want to write some mustache code like this for readability:

> {{this.$.Name}}
>
> {{this.$.Name}}

but when I do, the HTML looks like this:

> name name

I don't want any whitespace between the two names, I want it to look like this:

> namename

But I want indentation in the .hbs file, is there a way to have both with mustache?

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars has a feature called [whitespace control](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#whitespace-control):

> Template whitespace may be omitted from either side of any mustache statement by adding a `~` character by the braces. When applied all whitespace on that side will be removed up to the first handlebars expression or non-whitespace character on that side.

In your case, you'd do something like:

```
{{this.$.Name~}}
{{~this.$.Name}}
```

[View this Handlebars Playground for an interactive example](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22The%20below%20div%20does%20not%20have%20whitespace%20control%5Cn%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%20%20%7B%7B%24.firstName%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%7B%7B%24.lastName%7D%7D%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%5Cn%5CnThe%20below%20div%20DOES%20have%20whitespace%20control%5Cn%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%20%20%7B%7B%24.firstName%7E%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%7B%7B%7E%24.lastName%7D%7D%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%5Cn%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%5C%22%24%5C%22%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5C%22firstName%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22John%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5C%22lastName%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22Smith%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22The%20below%20div%20does%20not%20have%20whitespace%20control%5Cn%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%20%20John%5Cn%20%20Smith%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%5Cn%5CnThe%20below%20div%20DOES%20have%20whitespace%20control%5Cn%3Cdiv%3E%5Cn%20%20JohnSmith%5Cn%3C%2Fdiv%3E%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.6%22%7D).